# GCC warns me of passing void function to thrd_start_t

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc

EDIT: The issue was solved by changing the function type to int!

I am making a test program for multithreading using the threads.h library on Linux using the GCC compiler. I have been recommended by websites to use void when creating the function that a thread will use. However, using the void type results in one warning and one note: `main.c:6:28: warning: passing argument 2 of 'thrd_create' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]` and `/usr/include/threads.h:79:53: note: expected 'thread_start_t' {aka 'int(*) (void*)} but argument is of '(void*)()'`. I have three source files:

main.c:

```
// . . .
int main() {
    thrd_t job1;
    thrd_create(&job1, tjob1, NULL);
    thrd_join(job1, NULL);
// . . .
```

jobs.h:

```
void tjob1();
void tjob2();
void tjob3();
```

and jobs.c:

```
// . . .
void tjob1(void) {
    system("date");
    printf("Doing jobs...");
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        system("date");
    }
}
// . . .
```

Should I be concerned about the note and warning and how do I fix it? I have tried making tjob1 an int void, which threw an error, and I have tried fixing tjob1 to `*tjob1` / `&tjob1`, which also resulted in errors. I have tried figuring out the ideal type for tjob1 and how to declare a function to be `int(*) (void*)`, but with no luck, as that is what thrd_start_t accepts.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `int(*) (void*)` is a function that returns an `int` and accepts a `void*` parameter. Like `int foo(void* arg)` If you don't need the context parameter in your function you can leave it unnamed like `int foo(void*)` Did you try that? What were the errors you received?

Comment: I just changed the function type with your recommendation, and it compiled with no errors! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Zeckma _"The issue was solved by changing the function type to int"_ - That's not enough. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`thrd_start_t` is a `typedef` for `int(*)(void*)` which means that your thread starting function, `tjob1`,  has the wrong signature. Since you obviously do not care about the argument passed to it (`NULL`) or the return value, this rewrite should suffice:

```c
int tjob1(void *dummy) { // correct return type and argument
    (void)dummy; // to quiet warnings about unused variables

    system("date");
    printf("Doing jobs...");
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        system("date");
    }

    return 0; // something has to be returned
}
```